# How to get objects based on existence of object of another model?

Tags: django, django-models

In my Django app I have the following models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET('deleted_user'))
    post_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key = True)
    content = models.CharField(max_length = 2000)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    original_poster = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                    on_delete=models.SET('deleted_user'),
                                    related_name='author')

class Following(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name='follows')
    followed_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name='followed')
```

I am using standard User model included in Django.

Now I would like to retrieve posts of all users that are followed by a given user. What is the simplest way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Use the double underscore to follow the relationships via the Following model.

```
Post.objects.filter(followed__user=my_user)
```